# reversed bias diode on GPIO

Tags: diodes, atmega, gpio

I was looking more into the GPIO pins of the ATmega328p and came across the simplified schematic of a I/O pin. The schematic includes two reversed biased diodes, one to the ground and one to the VCC. [image: I/O Pin Equivalent Schematic]

I could identify the use of the reversed biased diodes on the I/O pin.
What is the use of these diodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diodes are protection devices against short transients and ESD.

If the pin is pushed higher than system voltage the diode clamps the pin to about 0.7v above system voltage. Same goes for the diode to ground. If the pin is pulled lower than ground then the diode clamps the pin to -0.7v.

In both cases the internals of the processor can withstand 0.7v above VDD and 0.7v below VSS and are protected. This does not mean that you can apply 10v to a 3.3v processor and expect it to survive.

Comment: "In both cases the internals of the processor can withstand these voltages and are protected." - that's a bit overbroad. If you connect a 10V supply to a GPIO pin, the MCU is most definitely not going to be 'protected' on its own.

Comment: @NickJohnson Thank you, I made the appropriate edit.

Comment: I think it would be clearer to not say that at all. The protection diodes are intended to protect against ESD transients; sustained overvoltage needs external protection, such as a current limiting resistor.

Comment: Just to note, it is better to use schottky diodes in this application. Schottky clamp at a lower voltage, therefore allowing less of the over- or under-voltage to reach the processor port pin. Check out the RB751S40CT-ND.